# Put request parameters not getting set

Tags: java, http, parameters

This may be standard stuff but unable to get it wokring.
I'm using `org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods` for making Http request from my Java code. In one instance I've to make a PUT request and pass some parameters. I'm doing it the following way:

```
PutMethod putMethod = new PutMethod(url);
putMethod.getParams().setParameter("param1", "param1Value");
putMethod.getParams().setParameter("param2", "param2Value");
httpClient.executeMethod(putMethod);
```

But at the server, when it tries to read these parameters - it can only get `null`.

However, When I modify my `url` as `url?param1=param1Value&param2=param2Value` it works.

How do I get it working using setParameter method?

Answer (score 1):

To add Query Params to PutMethod, follow this method.

```
    NameValuePair[] putParameters = new NameValuePair[2];   
    putParameters[0] = new NameValuePair(Param1, value1);       
    putParameters[1] = new NameValuePair(Param2, value2);   


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    PutMethod putMethod = new PutMethod(url);       

    putMethod.setQueryString(putParameters);
```

Then Call,

```
int response = client.executeMethod(putMethod);
```

Instead of `putMethod.setQueryString(putParameters);` you could also use

> putMethod.setRequestBody(EncodingUtil.formUrlEncode(putParameters, "UTF-8"));
>   (This is deprecated)

**GetMethod, PostMethod have slight differences when adding Query Params compared to the above code.**

For More Code Examples : http://www.massapi.com/class/pu/PutMethod.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

your server side code has to support the `PUT` method

for example if its a Servlet you can include the method

```
doPUT(); // your put request will be delivered to this method
```

if you use REST based frameworks such as jersey

you can use

```
@PUT 
   Response yourPutMethod(){..}
```

Comment: Server-side does support PUT as I said it works when I pass the params as part of the url itself.

Comment: the URL in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with the request -- the user agent knows what URL is intended and the server must not attempt to apply the request to some other resource.

Comment: by  above statement - PUT can send the request body so that said resource can be modified